# How to add auto slideshow in Red Hood Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have downloaded and applied red hood template([Red Hood)](http://www.templateism.com/2013/11/red-hood-portfolio-blogger-template.html) in my blog. But I found that the slider does not slide automatically with timer. This is Red hood slider code ..

```
  <!-- slider -->

  <div class='slider-container'>

  <ul id='slider'>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/1.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/2.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/3.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/4.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/5.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/6.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/7.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/8.jpg'/></a></li>
  </ul>

  </div><!-- /slider -->
```

I just edited to

In Head element - I added -

```
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.fp-slides').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 4000,
    delay: 0,
    speed: 1000,
    next: '.slidesjs-next',
    prev: '.slidesjs-previous',

    continuous: 0,
    sync: 1,
    pause: 1,
    pauseOnPagerHover: 1,
    cleartype: true,
    cleartypeNoBg: true
});
});
  </script>
```

And also change the slider code in body to -

```
  <!-- slider -->
  <div class='slider-container'>
  <div class='fp-slides'>
    <ul id='slider'>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/1.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/2.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/3.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/4.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/5.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/6.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/7.jpg'/></a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><img src='http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/8.jpg'/></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div><!-- /slider -->
```

But No changes in result! If I am wrong or missing something to slide automatically, help me to get the result.

Comment: The link to the template seems broken.

Comment: sorry ! I'll update it now .

Comment: Maybe switch continuous to 1 may help?

Comment: testing ... (But this code is from other template that works sliding automatically)

Comment: not working bro ! Thank you for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the red hood template link given and used developer tools to understand which plugin is used for the slider.

Notice that you need to look for script which is applied on any of the HTML elements of slider HTML code.It turned out that the template is using boxslider plugin in ticker mode.

Here is the link showing example of this: [boxslider ticker mode](http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker)

Comment: Thank you! I found it from your answer !